# Textarea content is not rendering properly \n \b \r are not working properlly

Tags: java, html, tags, textarea, htmlelements

I entered some paragraph with text Alignment and saved that in DB. After got the text from DB and display in one `DIV` tag.I can view the text but Alignment is missing. When I investigate `\n \b \r` symbols are not reorganized by the browser. How can I solve the issue?

Comment: \b is a backspace. Why would you store that?

Comment: The control characters need to be encoded as HTML-Tags. Like `\r\n` becomes `<br>` and so on....

Comment: got the answer - <pre> tag resolve the Alignments issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

**Using PHP `preg_replace`**

You can use PHP preg_replace function to prettify your text. Let's say you stored your text in some variable called $var. You can use following to replace all \n with HTML 
 tag.

```
$var = "Your text goes here....";
$var = preg_replace( '/[\n\r]+/',"<br>", $var );
```

**Using HTML pre Tags**

You can simply use HTML pre tag to add some quick formatting  to your text. Just bind your text within `<pre>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/vRCy9/)

**// will not break line**

```
document.write('Foo \n bar')
```

**// will break line**

```
document.write('Foo <br> bar')
```

`\n`, backspace `\b`, carriage return `\r`, will not work.

Those characters are not treated in any special way in HTML, they are simply white spaces. If you want to create a line break in HTML, you have to use the `<br />` tag.